# 'für den Preis von ...' vs 'zum Preis von ...'

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expression

I came across these two sentences on different websites:

> ein Dreierset Hemden für den Preis von einem.
>
> Drei Päckchen Kaffee zum Preis von zwei.

Are the expressions 'für den Preis' and 'zum Preis' the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are exchangable, yes. The reason why there are two different ones is because either *für* and *zu* can also mark other things.

> Ich habe meinem Mann ein Dreierset Hemden für den Preis von einem zum Geburtstag geschenkt.
>
> Ich habe meinem Mann ein Dreierset Hemden zum Preis von einem zum Geburtstag geschenkt.

The first one is less confusing, the second one goes easier from the tongue.

> Ich habe ein Dreierset Hemden zum Preis von einem für meinen Mann gekauft.
>
> Ich habe ein Dreierset Hemden für den Preis von einem für meinen Mann gekauft.

Same here.

Comment: Dazu fällt einem "Ich hätte gerne einen Scheibenwischer für meinen Trabbi." - "OK, fairer Preis" ein.